# What is the helicopter in the background of this image of the V-22 Osprey?

Tags: military, helicopter, aircraft-identification

I found a photo of a V-22 Osprey alongside an unknown helicopter on the left corner:
[image]

Comment: [HH-53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_MH-53)

Comment: This is [Blackout](https://youtu.be/o1KrJWYDR7E), the coolest [Transfomers' Decepticon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Blackout_(Movie)) =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an [MH-53 Pave Low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_MH-53).  In the [Air Force Special Operations Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Special_Operations_Command) (AFSOC), the CV-22 replaced the MH-53, although there were several years when both were in the inventory.

From the look of the beach, this photo was taken near [Hurlburt Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurlburt_Field), Florida, which is where they were both based as the first CV-22's came on-line.  Hurlburt Field is also the headquarters of AFSOC.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a [Sikorsky MH-53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_MH-53) to me.

[image]
<sup>Airman Magazine, MSgt Dave Nolan / Public domain</sup>

Answer (score 4):

One of the countless [H-53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_H-53) variants and sub-variants, most likely a [MH-53J/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_MH-53#MH-53J/M).